# StringBuffer -> HTML

Tags: java, html, hibernate

I'm working with a StringBuffer a previous developer built inside of a hibernate application and have found something interesting in some of the `.append()` methods

```
sb.append("<td style=\"padding-left:5px\">~BFE~").append(MyField).append("~AFT~</td>");
```

This seems to only be added to each `<td>` that contain the primary key of any given table

This is probably something simple and I'm missing it as there was no comments written, but what is going on here exactly? I assume something Before & something After that's HTML related.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer, it was replaced ten years ago by StringBuilder.

Comment: `~` has no special meaning in HTML.

Comment: Probably does a replace down the road that styles Primary Keys to look different targeting BFE and AFT with squigglies.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you asking what ~BFE~ and ~AFT~ mean? I'm afraid that is something very specific to your app, and not HTML related.

Comment: maybe BeForE and AFTer?

Comment: @PeterLawrey, would StringBuffer cause a noticeable lag while rendering html as opposed to StringBuilder? Because I am experiencing this like whoa

Comment: StringBuilders and StringBuffers do not generate HTML they optimize string concatenation...which in this case just so happen to contain HTML...but it may cause performance issues

Comment: @ClayBanks unlikely but you might mistaking assume that using it is thread safe when it's not.  The Javadoc "As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, StringBuilder. The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for the code you posted:

```
sb.append("<td style=\"padding-left:5px\">~BFE~").append(MyField).append("~AFT~</td>");
```

If the 'MyField' attribute is '1234' then the following html will be printed out:

```
<td style="padding-left:5px">~BFE~1234~AFT~</td>
```

That is it.

Why the previous developer used BFE or AFT (besides for Before/After, see Logan Murphy's comment), who knows.  Maybe there is something that is parsing the html table and looking for BFE/AFT to find the MyValue value?

Side Note:

The whole StringBuffer vs StringBuilder discussion is just a bit of noise.  StringBuilder is by far the preferred way of building strings now (see Peter Lawrey's comment about StringBuffer vs StringBuilder).  But even then, behind this scenes Java will stream line string concatenation calls to use StringBuilder.

Meaning...

```
String html = "<td style=\"padding-left:5px\">~BFE~") + MyField +"~AFT~</td>"
```

is the same as...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<td style=\"padding-left:5px\">~BFE~").append(MyField).append("~AFT~</td>");
String html = sb.toString();
```

Comment: I'm glad this question evolved enough to actually teach me something I wouldn't have otherwise looked into. Thanks bro